# Are there more Nullstellensätze?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Over which fields $k$ is there a reasonable analogue of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz?

Here is a more precise formulation: let $k$ be an arbitrary field, $n$ a positive integer, and $R = k[t_1,..,t_n]$.  There is a natural relation between $k^n$ and $R$: for $x \in k^n$ and $f \in R$, $(x,f)$ lies in the relation if $f(x) = 0$.
This relation induces a Galois connection between the power set of $k^n$ and the set of all ideals of $R$ (both partially ordered by inclusion).  In more standard algebraic-geometric language, if $S$ is a subset of $k^n$ and $J$ is an ideal of $R$, put

$I(S) = \{f \in R \ | \ \forall x \in S, \ f(x) = 0\}$

and

$V(J) = \{x \in k^n \ | \ \forall f \in J, \ f(x) = 0\}$.

There are induced closure operators: for a subset $S$, $\overline{S} := V(I(S))$ and for an ideal $J$, $\overline{J} := I(V(S))$.

The closure operator on subsets is compatible with finite unions so is the closure operator for a topology on $k^n$, the Zariski topology.

The question is: what is the closure operator $I \mapsto \overline{I}$ on ideals of $R$?  By a Nullstellensatz, I mean a nice description of this closure operator.

Some remarks and examples:

1. Over any field $k$, one sees that $\overline{I}$ is a radical ideal hence contains $\operatorname{rad}(I) = \{x \in R \ | \ \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \ | \ x^n \in I\}$.

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says that $\overline{I} = \operatorname{rad}(I)$.

It is easy to see that if $\overline{I} = \operatorname{rad}(I)$ for all maximal ideals of $k[t]$, then $k$ is algebraically closed.

2. If $k$ is formally real, then for any ideal $I$ of $R$, $\overline{I}$ is a **real ideal**, i.e., $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in R, \ x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 \in I \implies x_1,\ldots,x_n \in I$.  Moreover, for any ideal $I$ in a commutative ring, there is a unique minimal real ideal containing $I$, its **real radical** $\mathbb{R}ad(I)$, which is the intersection of all real prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $I$.

If $k$ is real-closed, then for any ideal $I$ in $k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$, $\overline{I} = \mathbb{R}ad(I)$: this is Risler's Nullstellensatz.

3. There is also a Nullstellensatz for p-adically closed fields (in particular, for $p$-adic fields) due to Jarden and Roquette: see

[The Nullstellensatz over p-adically closed fields](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-32/issue-3/The-Nullstellensatz-over-p-adically-closed-fields/10.2969/jmsj/03230425.full)

> Are there further Nullstellensätze (say, for non-Henselian fields to rule out variations on 3)?

Although I haven't been precise on what a description of $\overline{I}$ means (I don't know how), it seems reasonable to guess that there is no good Nullstellensatz over a field like $\mathbb{Q}$ for which it is believed that [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) has a negative answer.  Briefly: if you had a system of polynomial equations $P_1,\ldots,P_m$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, then they have a simultaneous solution over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff
the closure of $\langle P_1,\ldots,P_m \rangle$ is a proper ideal, so if you had a sufficiently nice description of the closure operation, you could use it to answer H10 over $\mathbb{Q}$ affirmatively.

A case of persistent interest to me over recent years is that of a finite field.  In some sense this is the worst case, since it is not hard to show that the zero ideal in $k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ is closed iff $k$ is infinite.  Nevertheless, I vaguely feel like there should be something to say here, possibly something having to do with reduced polynomials -- i.e., for which each exponent of each variable is at most $\# k - 1$ -- as in one of the proofs of the [Chevalley-Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).

P.S.: I am aware of other algebraic results about $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ over a general field $k$ which, when $k$ is algebraically closed, imply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, e.g. that a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is a field is finite-dimensional over $k$, or that every prime ideal in $k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ is an intersection of maximal ideals.  These are interesting and useful, but here I am really interested in $I \mapsto \overline{I}$.

Comment: If I had a second vote, I would give it to you for using the correct plural of "Satz."

Comment: @Ben: In that case, please find an upvote to give to Georges Elencwajg, who informed me of this in an email some months ago.  (I had used an incorrect pluralization in some online lecture notes.)  Don't be fooled -- unfortunately, I speak no German.  

Comment: Hi Pete - welcome back!  I don't have time for a real answer... but have you seen the Ruckert Nullstellensatz?  It's a nullstellensatz for germs of holomorphic functions - I got interested in it a bit, due to a model-theoretic proof by Weispfenning (there's a model-theoretic approach to all the Nullstellensatz that I know).   

Comment: @Marty: No, I don't think I've seen it, but I'll check it out.  As for the model theory -- yes, of course that's part of where I'm coming from.  In fact I am teaching a short course on model theory as we speak (well, if we were to speak tomorrow afternoon at 2:15 pm EST), and I just typed up notes on the real Nullstellensatz following from the model completeness of real-closed fields.  

Comment: One reference for an analytic Nullstellensatz is this: http://archive.numdam.org/article/SHC_1960-1961__13_2_A6_0.pdf
(starting on page 15). In this series of exposes, k is a nondiscretely valued complete field.

Comment: If you want anther conscrete example there is a differential nullstellensatz for differentially closed fields. Actually there is a general model theoretic notion called model completeness which, in a certain sense, captures the idea of nulstellensatz. All the examples you mentioned can be seen as model completeness results.

Comment: I wouldn't propose it as an answer, because this is just a variation on the classical Nullstellensatz over an algebraically closed field in terms of infinitesimals, but there is this paper: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=BSMF_1978__106__399_0

The paper above is about characteristic zero, but there is version in positive characteristic as well (we just have to work with polynomials/series with divided powers); see the paper by the same author: J. Emsalem, Singularisation des courbes et passage au quotient generalisé, Comm. Algebra 9 (1981), no. 13, 1427–1454.

Comment: @‍Lars's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32559/are-there-more-nullstellensätze#comment73536_32559): [Houzel - Géométrie analytique locale - II](http://archive.numdam.org/item/SHC_1960-1961__13_2_A6_0).  @Denis-CharlesCisinski's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32559/are-there-more-nullstellensätze#comment182202_32559), I think (the link as written is dead): [Emsalem - Géométrie des points épais](http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1978__106__399_0).

Comment: I might have a new answer to add here, depending on how things go with my question about a possible “Nullstellensatz with nilpotents and I=J(V(I))”: https://mathoverflow.net/q/432151/44143

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If $k$ is a finite field with $q$ elements and $I$ an ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then $\overline I=I+I_0$, where $I_0=(x_1^q-x_1,\dots,x_n^q-x_n)$. This follows immediately from Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz applied to the algebraic closure of $k$, and the observation that any ideal extending $I_0$ is a radical ideal (as it contains all polynomials of the form $f^q-f$).

On an unrelated note, a more explicit description for the case of $k$ real-closed follows from Stengle’s (Positiv- and) Nullstellensatz: $f\in\overline I$ iff $-f^{2n}\in I+\Sigma$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, where $\Sigma$ is the set of all sums of squares of polynomials.

Comment: This is a very nice observation!  It came a long time after I originally posted the question and, though I apparently upvoted it at the time, I seem to have forgotten about it.  Does it appear in the literature anywhere?

Comment: This is a common knowledge in algebraic proof complexity. I have no idea who could have observed it first, but see e.g. the introduction to http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-73.1.1

Comment: @EmilJeřábek's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32559/are-there-more-nullstellensätze#comment266734_71872): [Beame, Impagliazzo, Krajíček, Pitassi, and Pudlák - Lower bounds on Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and propositional proofs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-73.1.1).

Answer (score 14):

Pete, a Nullstellensatz-like result for finite fields is the "Combinatorial Nullstellensatz" formulated by Noga Alon, and it does imply the Chevalley-Warning theorem.  Searching for CN will produce Alon's paper and several others on the first page of results.

Comment: Thanks, T.  I have seen the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz before, but I haven't really internalized it or appreciated its usefulness.  For instance, the derivation of Warning's Theorem from the CN reminds me a lot of Warning's proof of Warning's theorem.  I say this not to denigrate the result but just to be honest about my current level of understanding.  Any insight you can provide would be welcome: in particular, does it give further information about the closure operator in general, or just in a particular case as in p.1 of Alon's paper?

Comment: Just to be clear: I was not thinking about CN when I posted the question, and, in that it is in the same circle of results as Chevalley-Warning, it is quite plausible to me that it has something to do with a Hilbert-style Nullstellensatz over finite fields.  I appreciate the pointer. (+1.)  But it thickens the plot rather than definitively answering my question (not that I have any guarantee that a definitive answer exists...).  

Comment: [Alon - Combinatorial Nullstellensatz](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0963548398003411).

Answer (score 10):

[This paper](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:1987:33#456) by Laksov addressed your question in detail:

D. Laksov, Radicals and Hilbert Nullstellensatz for not necessarily algebraically closed fields,. L'Enseignement Mathematique, 33, 323-338 (1987)

There seems to be more work on this, so a MathSciNet search on papers that cited the one above would help, I think.

Comment: Thanks!  This indeed looks like exactly what I was interested in.

Answer (score 5):

A recent paper, [The Chromatic Nullstellensatz](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.09929), generalizes the theory to the world of ring spectra, which of course contain rings as a special case. The paper is even more general. It defines (on page 1) what it means for an $\infty$-category $C$ (or an object $A$ in $C$) to be Nullstellensatzian, then draws a connection to the classical Nullstellensatz: if $C$ is the category of rings, then every algebraically closed field is Nullstellensatzian. The authors then characterize when an $E_\infty$-algebra $R$ in the category $C$ of $K(n)$-local spectra is Nullstellensatzian.

Perhaps this more categorical approach will give a new way to look at the classical Nullstellensatz. Lastly, I saw Robert Burklund present this paper in Oslo last month and he gave the audience the chance to push back against the word "Nullstellensatzian." We being a bunch of homotopy theorists and motivic homotopy theorists didn't seem to have a problem with it, but if algebraists are horrified, it might not be too late to put the genie back in the bottle and change the name.

Comment: A small clarification: Burklund, Schlank, and Yuan remark in their paper that, as mentioned in [Emil Jerabek's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71872/), it's well-known that an ordinary ring is algebraically closed if and only if it is Nullstellensatzian -- see e.g. the paragraphs before and after Definition 1.1 in the introduction. What's not known is the generality in which algebraically closed / Nullstellensatzian objects in more homotopically-flavored categories can be related to algebraically closed fields in the category of rings (the known examples all do have some such relation).

Comment: @TimCampion Ah, ok, great! Thanks

Comment: I’d opt for a proper German suffix: perhaps *Nullstellensätzig*? Or *Nullstellensätzisch*?

Comment: Nullstellenbesetzt...